# Want to show two smooth manifolds are diffeomorphic

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider a smooth manifold $M = \{ (u,v) \in \mathbb{R^3} \times \mathbb{R^3} \mid \|u\|=\|v\|=1 \text{ with } u \perp v \}$, and want to show $M$ is diffeomorphic to $SO(3)$, the rotational group in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

I first define a map $f:M \rightarrow SO(3)$ by $(u,v) \mapsto [u,v,u \times v]$

How do I show $f$ is smooth with smooth inverse $f^{-1}$? And this is the only way to show diffeomorphism right?

Comment: It would also suffice to show that $f$ is bijective and has an invertible tangential at each point. Then the inverse function theorem implies that $f^{-1}$ is smooth.

Comment: Yes, the best way to show that two spaces are diffeomorphic is to find a diffeomorphism, such as the $f$ that you've found.  I don't know that it's the *only* way to show it, though.

In order to show that $f$ is smooth, it suffices to note that each of the functions
$$
(u,v)\mapsto u\\
(u,v)\mapsto v\\
(u,v)\mapsto u\times v
$$
are smooth.

Comment: $f$ is bijective is pretty clear from the fact $(u,v) \mapsto (u,v)$ is bijective  and cross product is also bijective. How do one show $f$ has invertible derivative at each point (i guess that's what you mean by "invertible tangential")? Just show $det(df)$ is zero?

Comment: In fact, bijectivity has nothing to do with bijectivity of the cross-product; the thing to note is that $[u,v,u \times v]$ is the unique matrix in $SO(3)$ whose first two columns are $u$ and $v$.  To show that this is indeed an element of $SO(3)$, note that the columns are orthonormal and that the determinant of the matrix is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

You're right: every element in $SO(3)$ is just a positively oriented basis of $\mathbb R^3$, and such a basis is determined by its two first vectors as you propose. In other words, one represents motions in $SO(3)$ by their orthogonal matrices with respect to the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$. Now $M\subset\mathbb S^2\times\mathbb S^2$ is defined by $h(u,v)=\langle u,v \rangle=0$ and  $h:\mathbb S^2\times\mathbb S^2\to\mathbb R$ is a submersion:
$$
d_{(u,v)}h(v,0)=\langle v,v\rangle=\|v\|^2\ne0.
$$ 
for any $(u,v)\in M$ (because $v\in T_u\mathbb S^2$). The map $f(u,v)=[u,v,u\times v]$ is smooth, because $L=[u,v,u\times v]$ is just the matrix of the motion  and vector products are algebraic operations with the coordinates of $u,v$. The inverse is given by $u=L(e_1), v=L(e_2)$, again smooth. Hope this helps!